# Can we retrieve back an object after converting it to (char *)

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, char

```
        msg->msgType = JOINREPLY;
        memcpy((char *)(msg+1), &memberNode->addr.addr, sizeof(memberNode->addr.addr));
        memcpy((char *)(msg+1) + 1 + sizeof(memberNode->addr.addr), &memberNode->memberList, sizeof(memberNode->memberList));
```

This is my msg which I want to send from one function by calling another function, which is `send((char *)msg, msgsize);`

The data structure for msg is

```
enum MsgTypes{
    JOINREQ,
    JOINREPLY,
    DUMMYLASTMSGTYPE,
    HEARTBEAT
};

typedef struct MessageHdr {
    enum MsgTypes msgType;
}MessageHdr;
```

`vector<MemberListEntry> memberList;` is the definition of memberList, as you can see memberList is a vector of type MemberListEntry, MemberListEntry has its own data.

```
int id;
short port;
long heartbeat;
long timestamp;
```

Since I am converting the complete memberList into (char *) is it possible to convert (char *) to memberList or MemberListEntry type again and iterate over it??

```
        MemberListEntry *ml;
        ml=(MemberListEntry *)malloc(sizeof(MemberListEntry));
        for(char *j=finalData; i < (int)string(finalData).length(); j = (char *)(j+ sizeof(MemberListEntry))){
            ml= (MemberListEntry *)j;
            i+=sizeof(MemberListEntry);


            idR=ml->getid();
            portR=ml->getport();
            heartbeatR=ml->getheartbeat();
            //Do some stuff
        }
```

The "finalData" is the data which I get after chopping off the msgType and the address which I was storing, pointing my pointer to the location where I store my  memberList in the char format.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include an field in your message header indicating the whole size of a message pack.

possibly like this:

```
typedef struct MessageHdr {
    enum MsgTypes msgType;
    unsigned int msgLength;
} MessageHdr;
```

The actual value stored in the msgLength field depends on the convention, e.g. it can vary from the whole message pack size or minus the size of the header, or simply the count of `MemberListEntry`s. use whatever you prefer.

You use `send((char *)msg, msgsize);` to send over a tcp socket. However, your peer cannot figure out the important `msgsize` value in order to rebuild the message data, unless you explicitly send it as part of your message header.

Then it should be trivial to rebuild them.

Firstly you should figure out how many entry exists in your message pack. Then you alloc a new vector of that size. finally you `memcpy` all data into the new vector, and everything should be ok.

---

**Principle #1: You cannot get information from nowhere.**

The `sizeof` works because the compiler knows the sizes. **They are predefined, by the specification, by the platform, or by the header files you `#include`d. They are fixed. And they never change.**

The `.length()` works because **the `std::vector` keep the length information for you under the scene.** You can check their corresponding header files yourself.

In short, **none of them comes from some fancy magics that automatically figure out what is contained in an arbitary memory area.**

In your case, the information - "the actual element count" - is critical. And it must be accessible to the peer in order to reconstruct the data structure.

**Priciple #2: Data structures that contain pointers in it cannot be send directly over network.**

A pointer is only valid in current process. You cannot blindly send pointer over network. So sending your clever `std::vector` does not work, either. Though the `std::vector` itself has fixed size and you can apply `sizeof` to it, it uses pointer internally to hold the actual data that can change dynamically.

---

Well, what you actually need is some kind of data marshalling / object serializing. You need to convert the data to some representation suitable for network transferring, and convert them back later. In the C++ realm, you have to do it yourself. There is no magic.

If you feel really boring implementing such a thing, consider using some high level language that handles object serializing for you. For example, Javascript has native support of the famous JSON format which is excellent in data exchanging. Or you can use C# which has a fast and efficient binary serializer with strong type.

Comment: That all can be done, but I am looking for some code to convert back from (char *) to the object, and as I have mentioned above memberList is a vector, type of MemberListEntry class. and elements to the vector can be added or deleted. so length cannot be fixed. moreover, it can always be found out by .length() or sizeof with proper logic. Entries are all mentioned in first part of code

Comment: Why can't the peer figure out the size of data from msgsize if we send msgsize outside the message packet? and why can't I do the way I am trying to do?

Comment: You should be aware of one thing: a char * is a pointer that refers to a block of memory of UNKNOWN size, unless there is a way to figure out the size otherwise. So no matter what you do, you need to keep the "Data Size" information somewhere, and make sure your peer can access this information.

Comment: The std::vector knows how many elements it have, because it maintains that information alongside the raw data that you have `memcpy`-ed. It is the standard library that did these dirty work for you, not some magic that can automatically knows how much data is contained in a raw char *.

Comment: I read somewhere that it can be converted back to the object as they both are pointers... and point to the memory location where it is stored

Comment: **Principle: You cannot get information from nowhere.** Is that hard to receive? Back to your question. Where do you expect to get the most critical information, **the actual data size**, from? `sizeof` works because the compiler knows what the size is. **These sizes are predefined, fixed and never change**. The `.length()` works because std::vector **keeps the size information behind the scene**, you can check the header files yourself. None of them works because there are some fancy magic that automatically figure out what is contained in an arbitary memory area.

Comment: **Principle #2: You cannot send data structure that contain pointers over network. They are meaningful only to the current process.** This should be easy to get too. So **Sending your clever std::vector directly does not help, either**. std::vector has fixed size (so you can use `sizeof` on it), but it uses pointers internally to hold the actual data (whose size can be changed dynamically). So you cannot send it directly. You must implement some kind of data marshalling in order to convert your data to a representation that is suitable for network transferring, and convert it back later.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to transfer data using char*, you can simply recast the data, given that you know its size, back to its original form, assuming there's been no data deformation or transformation, which TCP prevents.

`char*` is actually a sort of array in disguise, as arrays are actually just blocks of data stored adjacently in memory. In C:

`array[1] and 1[array]` are the same as they both access the data at the address of array incremented by 1.

So your data has just been "unformatted" into a raw data block. If you use a cast back to your original form to give it type, everything should be fine.

If your data contains pointers, you're screwed. Now you don't have the original memory address system to refer to, so how can you locate data? Unless you copy the memory addresses as well, you can't access pointers once they go across systems.

Comment: An important caveat here is that this only works for relatively trivial structures (such as the askers).  If your structure contains pointers, you'll need to deal with that special.